# Having difficulty extracting metadata from mp3 using paperclip in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I am a rails newb and even though I have checked the paperclip documentation on metadata extraction with mp3info, i can't get it to work in my current application. I am trying to extract metadata from a paperclip audio attachment before it is uploaded to S3, so that i can display the bitrate artist and title of the track. Here is my track.rb model below.

```
    class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :artist

    belongs_to :album

    validates :artist_id, presence: true

    has_attached_file :audio, storage: :s3, s3_credentials: {access_key_id: ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],
     secret_access_key: ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"]}, bucket: 'musicstreamdata'

    validates_attachment_content_type :audio, :content_type => [ 'audio/mpeg', 'audio/x-mpeg', 'audio/mp3', 'audio/x-mp3', 'audio/mpeg3', 'audio/x-mpeg3', 'audio/mpg', 'audio/x-mpg', 'audio/x-mpegaudio' ]

    validates :audio, presence: true

    before_save :extract_metadata

    serialize :metadata

      def audio?
        audio_content_type =~ %r{^audio/(?:mp3|mpeg|mpeg3|mpg|x-mp3|x-mpeg|x-mpeg3|x-mpegaudio|x-mpg)$}
      end

      def display_name
        @display_name ||= if audio? && metadata?
          artist, title = metadata.values_at('artist', 'title')
          title.present? ? [title, artist].compact.join(' - ').force_encoding('UTF-8') : audio_file_name
        else
          audio_file_name
        end
      end

        private

# Retrieves metadata for MP3s
    def extract_metadata
      return unless audio?
      path = audio.queued_for_write[:original].path
      open_opts = { :encoding => 'utf-8' }
      Mp3Info.open(path, open_opts) do |mp3info|
        self.metadata = mp3info.tag
      end
    end

end
```

after checking the rails console for metadata, (Track.last.metadata), the console returns a {} value for metadata.

When I use

```
<%= @track.audio.display_name %>
```

in the show view it displays a NoMethodError in Tracks#show.

Comment: What issue/error are you facing? What is the `metadata` value after the save?

Comment: Also try to properly format your code before posting it to stack overflow. Right now it looks really ugly and is difficult to read on account of the messy indentation.

Comment: I indented the code and spaced it out a bit better, hopefully now it's a bit more legible. The metadata value is {} after save.